# JMSSerializer and UTF-8 encoding error ( Symfony2.4 )

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8

I've got REST api which returns tasks/companies/notes/etc. On localhost it works fine, no matter what task description or company name I write, but I put my app on server and when I'm using signs like "łźążćę" there is error `Your data could not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8 characters." at app/endor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php line 36` .

Databases are the same, tables too, all config options are the same. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I use @VirtualProperty with method which cut string with **substr(str, start, length)** function.
This function is bad choice if you use UTF8. Instead, use **mb_substr**.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem by setting the database connection properties to transfer data with UTF-8 charset. This is how the `doctrine` section looks like in my `app/config/config.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default

        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                host:     %database_host%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
                options:
                    1002:  "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, as you can see in my question: [Symfony2 & FOSRestBundle: Getting UUID packed in a BINARY(16) field from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26659740/1900966).

I have managed to represent the binary field converting it to HEX in the log, but FOSRestBundle still returns the same exception.

Any improvements with yours?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, only in production. It turned out that one line in the database contained with the character `¨`, (U+00A8) which the serializer couldn't handle.

Removing the character solved the problem.